# Save R MICE Imputed Data as SPSS data

Tags: spss, mice

I am calling the R MICE routines into SPSS to do multiple imputations.  My question is how to save the multiple imputed data sets as SPSS files for later analyses.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

DLuo

Comment: Welcome to the site, @DLuo. Your question is *only* how to do this in SPSS. Thus this Q is off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). You might try one of the SPSS specific resources listed [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/spss/info).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to save SPSS datasets.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to save each imputed dataset as a CSV file, then load the CSV files in SPSS and save them as SPSS datasets.

For example, if you saved the result of the `mice()` function in variable `imp`, with 5 imputed datasets (the default), you could do:

```
for (i in 1:5)
{
   write.csv(complete(imp, i), file=paste("imp", i, ".csv", sep=""))
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to generate SPSS syntax to load the datasets automatically, you could try the `foreign` package, like this:

```
install.packages("foreign") #if package is not installed
library(foreign)
for (i in 1:5)
{
   write.foreign(complete(imp, i), datafile=paste("imp", i, ".txt", sep=""), codefile=paste("imp", i, ".sps", sep=""), package="SPSS")
}
```

Using this code, you would get 5 data files (saved as .txt files), and 5 syntax files to load the .txt files into SPSS.

Comment: Hi Patrick,

Thanks for the answer!  I tried the first approach but got the following message:

Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'imp1.csv': Permission denied

I then tried the alternative approach.  There was no error message, but I couldn’t find the saved files.  I assumed the files are saved under the names “imp1.txt”, “imp2.txt”, etc., and used Windows Explorer to search for them, but nothing turned up.  Did I miss anything?

Thanks!

DLuo

Comment: Type `getwd()` to see where the files are saved. You can change the working directory by typing e.g. `setwd("c:/users/DLuo/desktop")`. If you pick a valid directory to which you have administrative access, this should fix your problems.

Comment: Hi Patrick,  That seemed to have solved the problem.  Thanks a lot!